# Logically partition bundles in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

We are using create-react-app to build a single page app.

We want to be able to share some of the views of this app with other applications. Idea was to generate two bundles, first one which is everything and a second one, which the external application will include and will only contain the views they should see (this, by the way, is not meant to be used as a security restriction)

I've read about code-splitting and how it can be used to dynamically load views. My understanding is that Webpack will split up the bundles based on how you use code-splitting. 
I am not sure I can get this to do what I am trying to do.

Is there a way to, within create-react-app, to say:

- Bundle1 should contain: a.js, b.js, a.css
- Bundle2 should contain: a.js, a.css

Or is there another way to handle what I was describing?

Comment: I think you should not use code splitting for your case. Because even though you will be able to create two bundles using webpack, those bundles would still be coupled to each other. So you won't be able to share one bundle with "different" application.

Comment: I see your point... So with code splitting I guess there is an "entry" bundle correct? This entry bundle is what the external application would "include"?

Comment: Yes. There will be an entry bundle. And if you have created bundle-2 by code splitting, then that bundle will be loaded lazily by entry bundle when required.

Comment: I know know what to do. Thanks for your help. If you add your comment as an answer, I will mark it.